# Removing Numix icon package from Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: icons, numix

How to remove Numix icon package from Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the icons just run

```
sudo apt-get purge numix-icon-theme
```

If you want to remove the PPA they came from too

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:numix/ppa
```

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type:

> sudo apt-get remove --purge icon-theme-name